# How can I specify JSLint property of a JS object to be an array always?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I check my code with JSLint after coding. Sometimes I forget to set the property to array, and write it as an object. How can I specify one of property of a object to be an array, for example I have a JS objects:

```
var writer = {
   name: 'Susan',
   surname: 'Gøgenheïm',
   books: [
    {
       title: 'The Greatest Book Ever',
       year: 2001
    },
    {
        title: 'Ololo, I am',
        year: 2010
    }, ....
   ]
}
```

And the 'books' field always must be an array. Even if it is a simple object, like here:

```
var writer = {
   name: 'Susan',
   surname: 'Gøgenheïm',
   books: [{
       title: 'The Greatest Book Ever',
       year: 2001
    }]
}
```

I haven't found any directives here http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Comment: JSLint won't help, as it doesn't do any type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use JSlint for type checking  purposes like you try. It's made for checking the syntax (and Crockfords feelings of beautiful whitespace) of your code  and since your syntax is perfectly valid with or without an array definition, JSlint won't mark it as mistake.

If you want to ensure type safety, take a look at [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) .